# Opening a Downloaded file in a PHP and mysql does not work

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I'm trying make an application that uploads then download the file but I'm having a problem in opening a file except for the txt file. I get an error that says"failed to open".

Please help me to fix this problem so I provided my code.

Thank you.

so here's my code:

upload.php

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0)

{

$fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

$tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];

fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];

$fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

$fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');

$content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));

$content = addslashes($content);

fclose($fp);

if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())

{

$fileName = addslashes($fileName);

}

include_once 'dbConnect.php';

$query = "INSERT INTO gravator (name, size, type, content ) ".

"VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$content')";

mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die('Error, query failed');

echo " File $fileName uploaded";

}

?>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<table width="350" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">

<tbody>

<tr>

<td width="246">

<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000" />

<input id="userfile" type="file" name="userfile" /></td>

<td width="80"><input id="upload" type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload 
" /></td>
</tr>

</tbody>

</table>

</form>
```

upload.php

```
<?php

include_once 'dbConnect.php';

$sql = "Select * from gravator";

$res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die('Error, query failed');

if(isset($_GET['id'])) { // if id is set then get the file with the id from   
database

$id = $_GET['id'];

$query = "SELECT name, type, size, content FROM gravator WHERE id = $id";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die('Error, query failed');

list($name, $type, $size, $content) =

mysqli_fetch_array($result);

header("Content-length: $size");

header("Content-type: $type");

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");

echo $content; exit;

}

?>
<?php

$query = "SELECT id, name FROM gravator";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die('Error, query failed');

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)

{

echo "Database is empty";

}

else

{

while(list($id, $name) = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

{

?>

<a href="download.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $name; ?></a>

<?php

}

}

?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @tadman noted sir. I did not use it at first because I was trying to practice on how to upload and download, but thanks for the heads up tho

Comment: Nothing wrong with learning. Just be sure not to pick up any bad habits. Anything that references "magic quotes" is dangerously out of date so try and find current references. [PHP the Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) is a good place to start.

Comment: I think you'll have to debug what variables you're using for opening files. I strongly recommend using a string you control, not something supplied by the user, to avoid any security problems. For example, [generate a unique ID](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) to use as the filename and then you have a known-good path. Store in the database the original filename if that's still relevant later on.

Comment: @tadman Yes i'm using a unique ID for the file. it downloaded successfully but it seems it cannot open the file